# grepl with regex

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a difficulty using grepl with regex.

Here is a small example:

I have a character vector:

```
text <- c(

  "D_Purpose__Repairs" ,
  "Age" ,
  "F_Job"  
)
```

And I want to select the words that start with D_ or F_.  So I write:

```
grepl("\\>D_.+ | \\>F_.+", text)

grepl("\\D_.+ | \\F_.+", text)

grepl("\\^D_.+ | \\^F_.+", text)
```

However this returns:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong and how should I correct my code?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to (and must not) escape the caret character with backslashes, and you can't put extra whitespace in your regex around the |.  This works as you intend:

```
> grepl("^D_.+|^F_.+", text)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Some comments on your patterns:

- `\>D_.+ | \>F_.+` - here, `\>` matches the end of word position while the actual position here is a *start* of a word (so, you might want to try with `\<'). Also, the spaces around`|`are meaningful, you should not add them unless you use a`perl=TRUE`with a`(?x)` modifier.
- `\D_.+ | \F_.+` is a malformed patter since `\F` is an unknown regex escape. `\D` matches any char but a digit, and is clearly something you did not expect.
- `\^D_.+ | \^F_.+` is the closest, but there are redundant spaces again, and the escaped `^`  match literal caret symbols. If you do not escape carets they match the start of string positions.

Now, the most efficient pattern here is

```
grepl("^[DF]_.+", text)
```

Meaning:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[DF]` -  either `D` or `F` letters
- `_` - a literal underscore
- `.+` - any 1+ chars as many as possible up to the end of the string.